# Return an object from an object method in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
A = {
    f1: function() {
        return {
            a: function(){ alert('sss'); }
        }
    }
}

A.f1().a();
```

Why is it used in this way?

Why is the method `a()` bound to A.f1()?

Comment: I really don't understand what the question is... Is something not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: I used to think 'A.f1().a()' shouldn't work,because method a() is not belong to f1().

Comment: `a` does not belong to the function `f1`, it belongs to the value returned *by* invoking `f1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do as below:

```
var x = A.f1();
```

What you get on to x is the object returned by the f1 function. which is:

```
{
   a: function(){ alert('sss'); }
}
```

now the object 'x' has function a() on it. You can call that function as:

```
x.a();
```

Which is exatly similar to:

```
A.f1().a();
```

Answer (score 1):

Member function `f1` of `A` returns an object literal with its member `a` set to a function. It could've also been written as:

```
A = {
   f1: {
        a: function() { alert('sss'); }
    }
}

A.f1.a();
```

Returning an object could in this case be personal preference. There is no functional difference between these two examples.

Comment: His is a sort of Factory method, while yours is Singleton type ?